# Size limit on the size of strings in an ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

I need to display 5 different groups of strings. Some of the items in these strings are one or two sentences long. I was considering using an expandablelistview. The user could click one of the 5 categories and it would open up with all the strings.

Is there a string cut off for strings in an expandablelistview and listview or a way to display more then a sentence of information? I don't want the strings to get cut off. Note, I am not asking about the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HappyStuff extends ExpandableListActivity {

private static final String NAME = "NAME";
private static final String IS_EVEN = "IS_EVEN";
private ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);

    List<Map<String, String>> someData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    List<List<Map<String, String>>> someotherData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();
//FROM HERE
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        Map<String, String> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        someData.add(curGroupMap);
        curGroupMap.put(NAME, "It's a wonderful life");
        curGroupMap.put(IS_EVEN, (i % 2 == 0) ? "This group is even" : "This group is odd");

        List<Map<String, String>> children3 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        {
            Map<String, String> curChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            children3.add(curChildMap);
            curChildMap.put(IS_EVEN,  "And it's a beautiful day in the neighborhood");
        }
        someotherdata.add(children3);
    }
//TO HERE
//YOU CAN JUST KEEP ON ADDING NEW INSTANCES 
  supermagnificentAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            someData,
            R.layout.somespecialtypeoflayout,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 },
            childData,
            R.layout.rowsimpleitemlist2,
            new String[] { NAME, IS_EVEN },
            new int[] { R.id.text1, R.id.text2 }
            );
    setListAdapter(supermagnificentAdapter);
}

}
```

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to show me? My question was about the limits of the characters of a string.

Comment: Maybe I did misunderstand your question. I was thinking that you could put as many strings as you like into the list with as many sentences as you wanted.